# model.cuda() in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

If I call `model.cuda()` in pytorch where model is a subclass of `nn.Module`, and say if I have four GPUs, how it will utilize the four GPUs and how do I know which GPUs that are using?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`model.cuda()` by default will send your model to the "current device", which can be set with `torch.cuda.set_device(device)`.

An alternative way to send the model to a specific device is `model.to(torch.device('cuda:0'))`.

This, of course, is subject to the device visibility specified in the environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`.

You can check GPU usage with [`nvidia-smi`](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-system-management-interface). Also, [`nvtop`](https://github.com/Syllo/nvtop) is very nice for this.

The standard way in PyTorch to train a model in multiple GPUs is to use [`nn.DataParallel`](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/data_parallel_tutorial.html) which copies the model to the GPUs and during training splits the batch among them and combines the individual outputs.

Comment: If a user has two GPU's, and the 1st GPU is AMD which is not cuda-capable, and the 2nd GPU is NVIDIA, will it still be correct to say model.half().to("cuda:0"), or do I need some logic to check the index (i.e. would the correct input be "cuda:1" in that case and if so how can I detect that?)

Comment: @pete please post your doubt as a new question

Comment: Ok, I asked here https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/109682/when-would-i-use-model-tocuda1-as-opposed-to-model-tocuda0